# Why I can not sign in to github account in just installed visual studio on fresh windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio, github

Why I can not sign in to github account in just installed visual studio on fresh windows 10?

I mean I am pressing the thing and it just wont do anythng? It supposed to open like a browser and let me login. Y U microsoft so unfriendly to github?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the problem was that the default browser was not selected, so make sure to select the default browser like in the picture below:

P.S. For default apps navigation:
Select the Start  button, and then type Default apps.
In the search results, select Default apps.
Under Web browser, select the browser currently listed, and then select Microsoft Edge or another browser.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-default-browser-in-windows-10-020c58c6-7d77-797a-b74e-8f07946c5db6

[image]